# How to save image by JavaScript (from browser)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Consider an image loaded as

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
```

How can I add a save button to save the image from the browser loaded image instead of connecting to the server again to download the image from `src`.

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", 
function(){
// Save the image from the browser cache without connecting to the server again
});
```

In fact, I want to mimic the browser's `Save image as...`

For example, imagine the image is very large. I do not want to transfer the image data again. I want to save the loaded image, as `Save image as...` in Chrome does.

Comment: no, I want to make the users able to save an image from the loaded image in the DOM element rather than downloading it again from the server.

Comment: `<a href="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" download>Save image</a>`, though its not supported by all browsers.

Comment: @putvande it will download the image again.

Comment: How do you know that doesn't happen when you do a "save image as"?

Comment: @putvande when you hit `Save image as" on a large image in Chrome, the image is saved instantly with no data transfer on the internet connection.

Comment: So you have tried my suggestion already and tell me this actually goes to the server to request the image again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I fetched the image through a XMLHttpRequest request then used the raw image as a data url.

```
 // credit to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-convert-the-image-into-a-base64-string-using-JavaScript

function toDataURL(url, callback) {
       var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
       httpRequest.onload = function() {
          var fileReader = new FileReader();
             fileReader.onloadend = function() {
                callback(fileReader.result);
             }
             fileReader.readAsDataURL(httpRequest.response);
       };
       httpRequest.open('GET', url);
       httpRequest.responseType = 'blob';
       httpRequest.send();
    }
    toDataURL(
       'http://placehold.it/512x512',
        function(dataUrl) {
          document.write('<a href="'+dataUrl+'" download>Save as</a><img src="'+dataUrl+'"></a>');
       }
    )
```